# openstack create instance using specified xml file

Tags: libvirt, openstack-nova

When I used openatck to add many ports to the VM, I found that the PCI bus would not be enough.
So I need to modify the xml file of the VM through "virsh edit" command. But I have too many VMs to modify, is there any way to specify the xml file when creating the VM, or is there any openstack command to modify the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

The `virsh edit` command is just a short cut around

```
virsh dumpxml NAME > name.xml
$EDITOR name.xml
virsh define name.xml
```

so you can automate it with dumpxml + define avoiding the interactive editor.

Note it generally isn't a good idea to try to modify the XML config that OpenStack as created though, because it is liable to overwrite your changes in future.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. This solved my problem to some degree, but the solution I want most is to specify the xml file when creating the VM, instead of modifying it. This method ensures that I don't need to restart the VM. Anyway, thank you